# how to compare string[i] in c++

Tags: c++

```
int change(int x)
{
    for(auto i=x+1;i<line.length();i++)
    {
        if(line[i]=="-")
        {
            line[i]="+";
        }
        else if(line[i]=="+")
        {
            line[i]="-";
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

how to compare line[i] and just words like +, -

Answer (score 7):

Characters are denoted with single quotes `''`, not double quotes `""`. If you want to check a single char in a string, it would be like this:

`line[i] == '.'`

Answer (score 1):

- compare a character with another character, use `''` not `""`
- avoid loops by indices, if you can
- make sure your example code compiles (there is no `line` variable in your code)
- if a function returns an `int`, it should return an `int`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
    
// make functions for things you want to do
// so your code shows WHAT is it will do
char swap_plus_minus(const char c)
{
    if (c == '+') return '-';
    if (c == '-') return '+';
    return c;
}
    
int main()
{
    std::string line{ "hello++ world--" };
    
    // use range based for, so you cannot accidentally access
    // characters outside of string https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
    for (auto& c : line) c = swap_plus_minus(c);
    
    std::cout << line;
    return 0;
}
```